# How to interpret standard errors and t-values in error-correction terms?

Tags: econometrics, standard-error, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, eviews

When estimating a Vector Error Correction (VEC) model in EViews, the resulting output always shows the error-correction terms together with standard errors and t-values for the included variables, and I was wondering **if** and **how** these numbers matter for the results?

In my understanding, the presence of cointegration among two or more variables is determined based on the Johansen Cointegration Trace/Eigenvalue test, and the error correction equation(s) are then retrieved by estimating a VEC model of the variables. Following this procedure, however, all variables included in the VEC estimation enter the error correction term, even though some of them may have no long-term relation with the other variables whatsoever, and their SE/t-values change depending on the ordering specified. Do SE/t-values actually play a role in determining the correct cointegrating relation(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an estimated model, the standard errors and the t-values characterize the model coefficients but not the regressors.

In a VECM the standard error associated with the error correction term (ECT) is the standard error of the corresponding estimated coefficient (the loading coefficient); it does not concern the ECT itself.

Estimating a VECM is already one step past the cointegration analysis (typically Johansen's procedure) that you seem to be interested in.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, first the cointegrating vectors are estimated and the ECTs are formed. Only then (given the estimated ECTs) is VECM estimated. But I may be wrong about forming the ECTs before the VECM is being estimated... See also [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125811/estimation-of-vecm-via-ml-and-ols/126069#126069)